# How do I create a wallet with a 24-word phrase?

Tags: wallet

How do I create a wallet with a 24-word phrase instead of a 12-word phrase? I have used a couple software wallets such as Coinbase wallet and Exodus wallet which associate the wallet with a 12-word phrase. Basically, what software wallet can I use that is associated with a 24-word phrase?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Anonymous I do not feel 12 word wallets are safe enough

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `make_seed(264)` in console for [Electrum wallet](https://electrum.org/#download)

[image: Electrum-24words-seed]

> A typical seed has 12 words, which results in 132 bits of entropy in the choice of the seed.

https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/seedphrase.html

Comment: Electrum only supports bitcoin though.

Comment: So you don't feel safe with 12 words but feel safe by having bigger attack surface and use wallets that support multiple cryptocurrencies? Anyways this is bitcoin stackexchange so anything except bitcoin is off-topic